# Jetty 9.4 JSESSIONID not getting refreshed on session timeout

Tags: jetty-9, jsessionid

When my session getting timeout, JSESSIONID is not getting updated always. When we have session timeout, we set certain attributes invalid.
Cases where it fails to refresh, it finds old expired sessionId with invalid attributes and fails with error.

We are using jetty 9.4.14. Probably its related to some jetty configuration.

I also want to understand what is the protocol to update refresh JSESSIONID and what all paths I can check to figure out issues and fix them.

Also, should cookies clean up jsessionid upon session timeout